# New tcp connection is opened for every request in reactor-netty

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I'am trying to implement simple HTTP client with reactor-netty. But it doesn't work as I expect. There is the code

```java
        ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = ConnectionProvider.fixed("my-connection-pool", 5);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
                .create(connectionProvider)
                .tcpConfiguration(it -> it.host("localhost"))
                .port(8080)
                .keepAlive(true);

        Flux<HttpClientResponse> responseFlux = Flux.fromStream(IntStream.range(0, 1000).boxed())
                .flatMap(key -> httpClient
                        .get()
                        .uri("/" + key)
                        .response()
                );
        responseFlux.blockLast();
```

I expect only 5 tcp connections to be used. But netstat reports 1000 connections in status TIME_WAIT after program is finished.

```bash
$ netstat -tn | grep 8080 | head -1
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:33708         127.0.0.1:8080          TIME_WAIT
$ netstat -tn | grep 8080 | wc -l
1000
```

Have I missed something? Please help me.

Comment: response() Will automatically close low-level network connection after returned {@link Mono} terminates or is being cancelled. your can refer [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67176053/how-to-make-sure-rector-netty-http-client-create-fix-connection-to-http-server) and [issue1607](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1607)